# Get data form IN query without ordering

Tags: php

I get data from `IN` query in this format

```
SELECT * FROM wp_devices WHERE QID=’1′ and DId IN(36,71,37,39,38)
```

But they are displaying in this format `DId IN(36,37,38,39,71)` instead of `DId IN(36,71,37,39,38)`.

What should I do ?

Comment: Unless you specify `ORDER BY` the resulting order is undefined, and typically reflective of the way your RDBMS stores data on the disk and performs predicate matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add [order by clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to your query.
Because your order is a little bizarre you must to write [case workflow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_devices 
WHERE 
   QID='1' and 
   DId IN (36,71,37,39,38) 
ORDER BY
   case DId
     when 36 then 1
     when 71 then 2
     when 37 then 3
     when 39 then 4
     when 38 then 5
   end
```

I suppose that you work with mysql because you have another question that is tagged like this. Then you can simplify previous query using [field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_devices 
WHERE 
   QID='1' and 
   DId IN (36,71,37,39,38) 
ORDER BY
   field( DId, 36,71,37,39,38 )
```

Notice that field works with strings an an implicit type casting is maded.

Comment: both of above answered are perfect. thanks for your support.i owe you.

Comment: you are right , but i think second option is great when data has been come from db.cheers!!!

Comment: ok. thanks for your suggestion,i will keep this in mind in future

Answer (score 0):

Try actually manipulating the data before dumping it out? Each row will have its `DId` as one of the values in the row.

If you need a specific ordering, output the rows in that order *after* selecting them and retrieving the results.